# Parameter range to ensure stability using Routh Criterion

Tags: control-system, stability, routh

I have a question regarding Routh Stability for a characteristic equation of the form,

$$ 2S^4 + 2S^3 + 4S^2 + (k+1)S + 4 = 0 $$

I need to find the range of K for which the system will be stable. Upon using the Routh Criterion,

I ended up with two inequalities for K namely,

\$ K < 3\$ and \$ -K^2 + 2K -11 > 0 \$

The solution to the quadratic in K leads to two complex poles. How can I comment on the stability of the system?

I have attached a picture of the Routh table.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried plotting the two line/inequalities? If there is no real range in which they intersect there is no K values for which the system is stabilizable by just picking K

Comment: There is a small mistake in your calculations. It should be \$-k^2+2 k-5\$. Even so, what @jDAQ says holds.